# Is there a line continuation character, the opposite of \\?

Tags: line-breaking

Latex doesn't like line breaks in \[   \] mode. I have a very long expression that wraps my input screen and I keep getting compile errors because of typos in it---the mess of symbols and controls is difficult for me to parse (Latex has no problem, of course!). It would greatly help my editing if I could chop the expression up into shorter segments on separate lines. Is there a character I could put at the end of each line to "knit" them back together?

Comment: A line break should be fine in an equation, a blank line isn't. You could put a comment, using `%`, on a line you would like to be blank

Comment: @Willoughby. A case of early bad training. When I first started in Latex I kept getting errors in the environment, which I attributed to line breaks. I now see that I was wrong. I wish I'd asked this months ago!! Thank you. I'll leave this up for a little while and then delete it as there is no there there, it seems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inputs

```
\[
abc
\]
```

and

```
\[
a
b
c
\]
```

are perfectly equivalent. Endlines are converted to spaces (if not followed by a blank line) and spaces in math mode are ignored.

So you can break your long line as you please. Just don't introduce blank lines.

Comment: In case I'm not the only moron out there! Thanks again.